# Calculating the intersection point of a 3D line single Axis

Tags: java, math, geometry

Im trying to work out how to calculate where a 3D line(Two 3D points) and a Axis meets.

In my case im trying to calculate the intersection of a 3D Point to the Z Axis.

Lets say i give the line the coords of

```
Point1.X = 0
Point1.Y = 0
Point1.Z = 0

Point2.X = 50
Point2.Y = 50
Point2.Z = 50
```

And i want to calculate the intersect at Z 15,  how would i accomplish this?

I've thought about using interpolation, but it seems really inefficient here, i've looked at another posts and mathematical equations, but i dont really understand them enough to implement them into usable code.

Comment: Isn't an axis another line? Do want to find the line and plane intersection?

Comment: @matt No doesnt need to be a line, just an Axis. We are convering a 3D model into slices at intervals of the Z axis.

Comment: fixed my answer is you tried it and it didn't work

Comment: `Point1` is at the origin, and `Point2` is not on any axis. This line won't cross any axis anywhere else than the origin. `Z=15` is a plane, not an axis. *I've thought about using interpolation, but it seems really inefficient here* - this is the trivial textbook case of linear interpolation, what makes you think it's inefficient?

Comment: "No doesnt need to be a line, just an Axis." What is an axis, can you define it? An axis, by most normal definitions is a direction that passes through an origin. It sounds like you are making your own definition. eg. Z=15 is a plane where x, y are any values. Similarly for z=0 and x,y can be any values. That is a plane.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have vector A (like your point1) and B, then a straight line L through both points can be defined by

```
L(k) = A + k(B - A)
```

such that L(0) = A and L(1) = B. Suppose you want to find where

```
L(k).z = z_0
```

then you need to solve

```
A.z + k(B.z - A.z) = z_0
```

so the line L intersects the plane z = z_0 at

```
k = (z_0 - A.z) / (B.z - A.z)
```

If (B.z - A.z) is zero, either it does not intersect the plane z = z_0 anywhere, or it is in the plane everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
lambda = ( Point1.Z - Z ) / ( Point1.Z - Point2.Z )
Point3.X = Point1.X + lambda * (Point2.X - Point1.X)
Point3.Y = Point1.Y + lambda * (Point2.Y - Point1.Y)
Point3.Z = Z
```

Comment: How does this take into account the Z i want to intersect at?

Comment: sorry I thought you wanted the intersect with the Z=0 axis, I'm editing it